# package.version mismatch

Tags: julia

I am trying to solve [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaData/WeakRefStrings.jl/issues/82).

I understand that my version of the package is outdated (v1.7.2).
However, the package manager thinks I'm on the up-to-date version (v2.3.1).

```
(@v1.7) pkg> up
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General.toml`
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Manifest.toml`

(@v1.7) pkg> st Parsers
      Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
  [69de0a69] Parsers v2.3.1

julia> using Parsers

julia> Parsers.VERSION
v"1.7.2"
```

If I uninstall/reinstall the problem is still there:

```
(@v1.7) pkg> rm Parsers
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
  [69de0a69] - Parsers v2.3.1
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Manifest.toml`

julia> using Parsers
 │ Package Parsers not found, but a package named Parsers is available from a registry. 
 │ Install package?
 │   (@v1.7) pkg> add Parsers 
 └ (y/n) [y]: y
   Resolving package versions...
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
  [69de0a69] + Parsers v2.3.1
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Manifest.toml`
julia> using Parsers

julia> Parsers.VERSION
v"1.7.2"
```

Comment: You are required to post your issue here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site. If your link ever goes away,  it makes your question useless to anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PackageName.VERSION`, in contrast to what it intuitively looks like, does not give you the version of the package - it gives you the version of Julia currently installed. So `v"1.7.2"` refers to your installed version of Julia - you can verify this by loading any other package and trying `LoadedPackage.VERSION` on them, which should return the same value. (I'm not sure about the reason for such a design - having `VERSION` be a member of every module - but perhaps there's some value in `VERSION` being available as a local name within every module namespace.)

So you do have version 2.3.1 of Parsers installed, as the package manager indicates. The source of your original problem must be something else - perhaps it's worth asking as a separate question.

Comment: Ok, that's embarrassing...